# Possible Entity Framework Eager Loading Issue

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, eager-loading

I have this method

```cs
public ReadOnlyCollection<Auction> GetAuctionsByCriteria(Expression<Func<Auction, bool>>[] whereConditions, int pageSize, int pageIndex, out int total, AuctionCriteria criteria)
{
    // Applying filters
    var query = _composeFilter(criteria);

    // Adding external condition
    foreach (var whereCondition in whereConditions)
    {
        query = query.Where(whereCondition);
    }

    // Ordering and converting to list
    var orderBy = _getOrderBy(criteria);

    total = query.Count();
    List<Auction> list;
    if (criteria.Ascending)
        list = query.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
    else
        list = query.OrderByDescending(orderBy).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return new ReadOnlyCollection<Auction>(list);
}
```

The lines

Now, the Auction object has an associated Bids collection.  When this collection is large in the database (30 thousand+), the following lines in the above method time out.  When the collection is small they don't.

```cs
list = query.OrderBy(orderBy).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

and

```cs
list = query.OrderByDescending(orderBy).Skip(pageSize * pageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

I can't debug this (don't ask) but it would appear logical (to me) that the Bids collection is being eagerly loaded along with the Auctions.  How do I solve this problem?  Is it even an eager loading issue?

Comment: Can you show how Auction and Bids are associated and queried? Are the database indexes OK? Can you change indexes?

Comment: This seems like a timeout from the database. EF/Linq to Entities does not have any built-in timeout mechanism. Note that EF should load no more than pageSize of entities. This means that the time needed for loading these entities should be more or less the same if you have 100 entities or 1000000 entities. For me it feels that preparing entities (i.e. filtering, sorting etc.) takes too much time which indicates problems with your database.